# Scala dataframe value of column into another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I want to assign value of previous id into immediate next id.

For example, "id1" has value is "ab" and "id2" has value "ac".

I want to get the output "id2" has value "ab" "ac".

I have dataframe df as below:

```
id  value1 
id1  ab   
id1  ab
id2  ac     
id2  ac    
id3  abc    
id3  abc    
id3  abc
```

desired output

```
id  value1 value2
id1  ab   
id1  ab
id2  ac     ab
id2  ac     ab
id3  abc    ac
id3  abc    ac
id3  abc    ac
```

I used the following script

```
val w1 = Window.orderBy("id")
val snDF = df.withColumn("value2", lag($"value1", 2).over(w1))
```

But it gives me:

```
id  value1 value2
id1  ab   
id1  ab
id2  ac     ab
id2  ac     ab
id3  abc    ac
id3  abc    ac
id3  abc    abc
```

It is not the correct ouput. How can I get it ?

Thanks

Comment: I want to assign value of last id into next id e.g "d2" is an id and its value is "ac" and I want to make another column sn2 and assign a value ("ab") of previous id ("d1").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following should work for you

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val w1 = Window.orderBy("id")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("id", "value1")
    .agg(collect_list("value1").as("temp"))
    .withColumn("value2", lag($"value1", 1).over(w1))
    .withColumn("temp", explode(col("temp")))
    .drop("temp")
  .show(false)
```

You would get dataframe as

```
+---+------+------+
|id |value1|value2|
+---+------+------+
|id1|ab    |null  |
|id1|ab    |null  |
|id2|ac    |ab    |
|id2|ac    |ab    |
|id3|abc   |ac    |
|id3|abc   |ac    |
|id3|abc   |ac    |
+---+------+------+
```